# How to Changing the storage path when downloading files in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I downloaded a .Zip Files in Python using Selenium Webdriver(chrome) but, I can't change download directory. I have tried using various open sources, but all are saved in the'Downloads' folder, which is the default path. Can you tell me the code to change the download path? The code below is the most recently tested code.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("download.default_directory=mypath")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have always use this method, probably exists a better way to do it.
Adding download directory in prefs as a parameter of 'add_experimental_option'.

```
options = Options()
#options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("start-maximized") 
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
prefs = {"profile.default_content_settings.popups": 0,
                 "download.default_directory": r"C:\PROJECT\my_folder\\", #DOWNLOAD DIRECTORY
                 "directory_upgrade": True}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:/PROJECT/chromedriver.exe', options = options)
```